# Is it valid to get a correlation between moving averages?

Tags: correlation

I have a 10 day moving average of one set of return data for one stock and a ten day moving ave of another stock. 400 data points and correlating 390. Can I now get a correlation between the two or does it have to be by day? Thanks

Comment: I think it is fine to use the moving average, as while each day data point will be used 10 times, each moving average data point only counts 1/10th of this, and effectively with a large data set the moving average should yield the same correlation as a day by day analysis.  I say a large data set because the first 9 data points won't be counted a full 10 times, nor the last 9 data points, so provided you have much more than 18 moving average data points you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

The moving average is a smoothing (low-pass) filter, and if you then compute the correlation what you get is the correlation of filtered time series. If that is interesting to you, then yes, you can do that.

This correlation can however be both be higher or larger than the correlation of unfiltered time series, because the part that is attenuated by the filter (the high-frequency components) may contribute positively or negatively to the overall correlation.